# What is the user interface of SSRMS

Tags: iss, robotics, frames, robotic-arm

How does the control panel for Space Station Remote Manipulator System (the robotic arm) look like, and where is it located?

Is it some joysticks, or just a screen+keyboard? What kind of feedback (video?) does it provide? Does it control separate joints, or just position of the end of the arm? Maybe pre-programmed or automatic maneuvers like "walking" to given *Power and Data Grapple Fixture* or grappling an indicated PDGF automatically?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Like the SSRMS itself, it's rather complicated.

The "control panel" is called the Robotics Workstation (RWS).  There are two of them onboard the ISS.  One is in the US Lab, the other in the Cupola. An RWS consists of four main parts.

[image: Schematic drawing of the Robotics Workstation showing the components described below]

1. The Display and Control Panel, which has hardware switches for

- Camera routing and control
- Joint selection for single joint control mode
- Brakes
- Safing
- Auto Sequence control
- Special Purpose Dextrous Manipulator (aka Dextre) controls

Some limited feedback is provided here by illumination of the buttons.

[image: photograph of the Display and Control Panel]

2. The joysticks, one for rotation and one for translation.  The translational control on the left can be pushed in, pulled out, moved left or right, and/or up and down, for +/- directions in all three translations axes. The rotational control on the right can be pitched up or down, rolled left or right, and yawed (twisted) in both directions, for +/- motion in all rotational axes. This is a common setup with Shuttle piloting and Shuttle robotic arm controls working in the same fashion. A trigger on the rotational control allows the user to grapple or release.
3. Three dedicated CCTV monitors to show camera views.  The RWS generates and displays useful overlays on the monitors showing camera data, joint angles, alignment to grapple target, etc.  Critical feedback to the operator(s) can be provided through these overlays so that the operator(s) does not have to look away from the monitors.
4. A dedicated Portable Computer System (PCS) laptop used to call up the displays for controlling the SSRMS.  Additional PCSs can be used if desired.  Most of the detailed feedback to the operator(s) is shown on the PCS displays, and detailed control information is entered here.

This is the RWS in the Lab.
[image: Photograph of the RWS in the ISS Lab module]
And this is the RWS in the Cupola.
[image: Photograph of the RWS in the ISS Cupola module]

As far as modes of operation, as alluded to above, the operator can control one joint at a time, this is called Single Joint mode.  There are many modes of operation besides single joint

- FOR manual modes, in which the operator controls the motion of a given Frame
  of Reference, often the tip of the arm
- Pitch Plane mode, which rotates the pitch plane while maintaining
  the chosen FOR
- FOR Operator Commanded Auto Sequence (OCAS) mode, which moves the
  chosen FOR from a chosen initial to final position and attitude
- FOR Autosequence, which moves the chosen FOR through a
  preprogrammed sequence of points
- Joint OCAS, which moves the joints to an operator specified set of
  joint angles
- Joint Autosequence,which moves the joints through a    preprogrammed
  sequence of joint angles

Frames of Reference are key to SSRMS operations.

- The "external" frame is called the ISS Analysis Coordinate System
  (ISSACS). It's a right-handed frame with the origin at the center of
  the S0 Truss. The X axis points to ISS forward, the Z axis points to
  ISS nadir, and the Y axis points ISS starboard. When you need to describe the position and attitude of something relative to the entire ISS, this frame is useful.
  [image: Schematic drawing of the ISSACS FOR]
- A commonly used "internal" frame is the LEE (Latching End Effector,
  i.e. the tip of the arm) frame. This frame's origin is at the center of the LEE cavity.  Its X axis points out of the LEE, the Z axis is away from the LEE mounted camera, and the Y axis completes the right-handed system.  This frame is useful for describing the position and attitude of objects relative to the tip of the SSRMS.
  [image: Schematic drawing of the LEE frame]
- Each PDGF has its own frame, useful for describing the position and attitude of objects relative to the grapple fixture.
- Payloads grappled by the SSRMS have their own frames, sometimes
  defined in terms of berthing hardware or cameras.

Final note: Everything can be controlled from Mission Control, and often is.  Usually only highly critical operations like grappling or EVA support are done by the onboard crew.

Sources:

[ISS Robotic Systems and Operations](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwj1gdyv3qPSAhUl7IMKHYtaBmcQFggiMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nasa.gov%2Fcenters%2Fjohnson%2Fpdf%2F486042main_ISSRoboticsHumanFactorsPerspective.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGPiNprFdXV6-CfP0qGfmgWSBhCyQ&sig2=B0AMeLI7N6LV6h2pZJFQ1Q)

[ISS Coordinate Systems Manual](http://www.asi.org/adb/04/02/00/iss-coordinate-systems.pdf)

Personal notes

Comment: could you elaborate what Frame of Reference means in this context?

Comment: Could not find picture, attempted with words.

Comment: Is the RWS at Mission Control the same as on ISS?

Comment: No, it's all console commands there. No joysticks, no Display and Control panel.

Comment: Uh. Weird. You'd think without room, mass and "made for space" restrictions it could be more advanced than the on-board ones.

Comment: BTW, the joysticks work like Soyuz RCS controls, with push/pull for X translation, and twist for roll, or somehow else?

Comment: The translational control on the left can be pushed in, pulled out, moved left or right, and/or up and down, for +/- directions in all three translations axes.  The rotational control on the right can be pitched up or down, rolled left or right, and yawed (twisted) in both directions, for +/- motion in all rotational axes.  This is a common setup with Shuttle piloting and Shuttle robotic arm controls working in the same fashion.

Comment: Thanks for this great description! Do you happen to know the coordinates of the end effector camera (in the LEE frame), or can point to a reference that includes this information?

Comment: @Robin I may have that, I can look - what do you want, the position of the center of the lens?

Comment: @OrganicMarble yes, I'm interested in the position of the center of the lens in the LEE frame. Either the position itself, or (better, actually) a reference where I can find it would be great. I had a look at [NTRS](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/) already but did not find anything appropriate – thanks alot in advance.

Comment: I don't know that the info is explicitly on the internet, but knowing that the camera lines up with the grapple target pin when grappled, you can glean some info off the PDGF drawing in this document https://spacecraft.ssl.umd.edu/design_lib/42004.mss.user.ICD.2.pdf  That should give you everything but the setback from the tip of the LEE, it should not be too hard to estimate from some of the many good pictures available on the internet like https://archive.org/download/sts113-712-051/sts113-712-051.jpg

Comment: [Do you need to operate laptop computers to run the ISS SSRMS robots Canadarm2 & Dextre? What if there's a pressure loss and you're wearing a suit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/58357/12102)