# What is Earthy controlling in the ISS cupola?

Tags: iss, identify-this-object

ScienceAlert.com's [Astronauts on The Space Station Liked SpaceX's 'Earthy' Toy So Much They Kidnapped It](https://www.sciencealert.com/astronauts-on-the-space-station-liked-spacex-s-earthy-toy-so-much-they-kidnapped-it) shows a series of photos of Earthy, the new plushy member of the ISS crew.

In the photo below Earthy has one hand on what looks like a pretty important joystick control and one foot on a control panel. Both the joystick and some of the buttons have metal guards around them to protect from accidental manipulation.

What are the joystick and control panel for; what do they do?

---

Photo: [Source](https://www.sciencealert.com/astronauts-on-the-space-station-liked-spacex-s-earthy-toy-so-much-they-kidnapped-it) Anne McClain/NASA

[image: Earthy in the ISS cupola]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That is the space station robot arm control station aka the Robotics Workstation - one of two aboard the ISS. There's a long answer about its controls on the site already:
([What is the user interface of SSRMS](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20265/what-is-the-user-interface-of-ssrms))

Earthy is holding the Translational Hand Controller and her feet are resting on the Display and Control Panel.

Comment: Interesting that translational hand controllers look pretty much the same today as in the Apollo era.

Comment: Yep, and they look just like the ones on shuttle.

Comment: I thought they were T-shaped.

Comment: @Ikrase not in shuttle and ISS. http://www.collectspace.com/images/news-062611a/011.jpg Looks like Apollo's was though. https://history.nasa.gov/alsj/tnD7884HandContrlr.pdf